# Polymorphism & default values: can co-exist?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have a base class with a number of inherited derived classes. Something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f(string foo = "bar") {
        cout << foo << endl;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void f(string foo = "howdy") {
        cout << foo << endl;
    }
};

class C: public A {
public:
    void f(string foo = "something") {
        cout << foo << endl;
    }
};
```

I inherited just two classes for brevity.
This is the main:

```
A* aArray[] = {
    new B,
    new C,
};

int main() {
    aArray[0]->f();
    aArray[0]->f();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, the output that I get back is:

```
bar
bar
```

Just like how if the compiler ignores the default arguments of the overridden functions.
Is this normal, or there is something that I'm doing wrong or that I'm missing?

Comment: The default arguments may be making the function signatures different.  Turn your warnings up to maximum and recompile.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: So the solution which could be? It's ok to remove the default argument in the base class virtual functions and leave them in the inherited overridden functions?

Comment: @Overflowh: Try an experiment:  remove the default assignments in the function signature and retest.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I tried first to remove only the default arguments in the base class and it doesn't work. Then I tried to remove *all* the default arguments in the program, and the error is still there.. Also if now it prints the correct values.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Ok, after some try now everything works. The response is that the default arguments cannot be putted anywhere. Neither in the base class nor in the derived class otherwise the compiler will complain saying that the functions have different signatures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default values are statically binded. In other words, they do not have polymorphhic behavior. That's why you saw

```
 bar
 bar
```

instead of those default values in the derived classes' virtual functions.

According to Effective C+:

> If default parameter values were dynamically bound, compilers would have to come up with a way to determine the appropriate default values for parameters of virtual functions at runtime, which would be slower and more complicated than the current mechanism of determining them during compilation.